# Google Chrome - Crash Dump Location

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, crash-dumps

I'm trying to debug a page in a web app that keeps crashing Chrome ("Aw, snap!" error). I've enabled/disabled automatic crash reporting, tried logging with  `google-chrome --enable-logging --v=1`, (as well as various levels of verbosity), and all I get is a "crash dump ID" in the `chrome_debug.log` [chrome://crashes](http://chrome://crashes) Shows all of the dump IDs, but no actual dump file

I see [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848585/how-to-read-a-google-chrome-crash-dump-with-windbg) referring to reading the dump files, but I can't find the dump files themselves (just the ID).

Grepping for the crash ID in `/tmp` and `~/.config/google-chrome/` turns up nothing, but the `~/.config/google-chrome/chrome_debug.log` shows that *something* was sent:

```
--2015-04-06 11:10:00--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 74.125.228.224, 74.125.228.225, 74.125.228.231, ...
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|74.125.228.224|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/3’

     0K
 Crash dump id:  7dac9d5d58258264
```

Any ideas on where to find the actual file/data that's sent?

Details: 
Chrome version: 40.0.2214.111 (Official Build)
Linux Mint 16 (Petra)

Edit: Some extra info:

```
curtis@localhost:-$ tail -n 5 uploads.log && echo $(pwd)
1428584493,ddc357e4600a49e6
1428584497,7ac16455c152381a
1428589439,d00ad6f5e6426f3d
1428934450,66b3f722430511e8
1428939578,7a2efc2b681515d1
/home/curtis/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports

curtis@localhost:-$ ll -a
total 12
drwx------ 2 curtis curtis 4096 Apr  6 11:32 .
drwx------ 9 curtis curtis 4096 Apr 13 11:43 ..
-rw------- 1 curtis curtis 3291 Apr 13 11:39 uploads.log
```

[image: Info in chrome://crashes matches up to <code>uploads.log</code>]

Automatic reporting **is** enabled...
[image: Automatic Reporting **is** enabled]

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not on Linux, but, I do use Chrome on Windows.  Within the Chrome "advanced settings", there's a flag for _Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google_.  Do you have that flag also?  Is it checked?

Comment: It looks like the default directory is /tmp and extension is .dmp, so I would look for /tmp/7dac9d5d58258264.dmp in your example, but I'm not sure if it deletes the file on a successful send..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `*.dmp` files are stored in `/tmp/`, and this has nothing to do with the "Automatic crash reporting" checkbox. The file is also not related to the hash stored in `~/.config/google-chrome/`

In `~/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports/uploads.log`:

```
1429189585,5bddea9f7433e3da
```

From using , the crash dump file for this particular report was:

```
chromium-renderer-minidump-2113a256de381bce.dmp
```

**Solution:**

```
root@localhost:-$ mkdir /tmp/misc && chmod 777 /tmp/misc
root@localhost:-$ cd /tmp
root@localhost:-$ watch -n 1 'find . -mmin -1 -exec cp {} /tmp/misc/ \;'
```

Then, as a regular user (not root):

```
google-chrome --enable-logging --v=1
```

Once you see files created by the `watch` command, run:

```
root@localhost:-$ ls -l
-rw-------  1 root root 230432 Apr 16 09:06 chromium-renderer-minidump-2113a256de381bce.dmp
-rw-------  1 root root 230264 Apr 16 09:12 chromium-renderer-minidump-95889ebac3d8ac81.dmp
-rw-------  1 root root 231264 Apr 16 09:13 chromium-renderer-minidump-da0752adcba4e7ca.dmp
-rw-------  1 root root 236246 Apr 16 09:12 chromium-upload-56dc27ccc3570a10
-rw-------  1 root root 237247 Apr 16 09:13 chromium-upload-5cebb028232dd944
```

*Now* you can use breakpad to work on the `*.dmp` files.

Comment: i don't have a /tmp/misc directory, and there are no "*.dmp" files under /tmp (there are lots of crashes in chrome://crashes however!

Answer (score 7):

### Google Chrome - Crash Dump Location

To generate the Crash Dump locally,

```
 CHROME_HEADLESS=1 google-chrome
```

The `.dmp` files are then stored in `~/.config/google-chrome/Crash Reports`

### Produce Stack Trace

1. Check out and add [depot_tools](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools) to your PATH (used to build [breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad))

   ```
   git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools
   export PATH=`pwd`/depot_tools:"$PATH"
   ```
2. Check out and build [breakpad](https://chromium.googlesource.com/breakpad/breakpad) (using fetch from [depot_tools](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools))

   ```
   mkdir breakpad && cd breakpad
   fetch breakpad
   cd src
   ./config && make
   ```
3. To produce stack trace without symbols:

   ```
   breakpad/src/processor/minidump_stackwalk -m /path/to/minidump
   ```

More here https://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps

### Personally Preferred Method

1. Enable crash reporting:

   Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings > Tick "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google"
2. Go to chrome://crashes > File bug > Takes you to crbug.com > Complete 
   report leaving the auto-added `report_id field` unchanged.
3. Someone from the Chrome/Chromium team will follow up. They can provide
   you with your stack trace and aid at resolving the issue.

Comment: Shouldn't ./config be ./configure?