# Analyse crash report in chrome os

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I've got a chrome os app crashing regularly and causing all other chrome processes to crash as well.

I'm seeing crash reports in `chrome://crashes`, but no way to see the details of the report. I also can't find any minidump files to analyse.

What is the way to get crash report internals in chrome os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29474549/google-chrome-crash-dump-location).

> ```
> root@localhost:-$ mkdir /tmp/misc && chmod 777 /tmp/misc
> root@localhost:-$ cd /tmp
> root@localhost:-$ watch -n 1 'find . -mmin -1 -exec cp {} /tmp/misc/ \;'
> ```
>
> Then, as a regular user (not root):
>
> ```
> google-chrome --enable-logging --v=1
> ```
>
> Once you see files created by the `watch` command, run:
>
> ```
> root@localhost:-$ ls -l
> -rw-------  1 root root 230432 Apr 16 09:06 chromium-renderer-minidump-2113a256de381bce.dmp
> -rw-------  1 root root 230264 Apr 16 09:12 chromium-renderer-minidump-95889ebac3d8ac81.dmp
> -rw-------  1 root root 231264 Apr 16 09:13 chromium-renderer-minidump-da0752adcba4e7ca.dmp
> -rw-------  1 root root 236246 Apr 16 09:12 chromium-upload-56dc27ccc3570a10
> -rw-------  1 root root 237247 Apr 16 09:13 chromium-upload-5cebb028232dd944
> ```
>
> Now you can use breakpad to work on the `*.dmp` files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in dev mode in order to access the crash reports.  There's no way otherwise to access where the crashes are saved (system crashes under /var/spool/crash and browser/user crashes under /home/chronos/*/crash/).

However, if you're using official Chrome OS builds, we don't currently publish the symbols for the binaries, so it'll probably be a bit difficult to debug using those minidumps.